# Razor Partial View Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I'm following the example website being built in [Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210079) (but using Razor instead of ASPX as I go along).

However, I've hit a snag with a partial view. I'm getting the following error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
'SportsStore.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model
item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SportsStore.WebUI.Models.NavLink]'.
```

Here are the relevant files:

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/global.css")" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")"><script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>SPORTS STORE</h1>
    </header>
    <nav class="categories">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); } // <!-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM -->
    </nav>
    <section id="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**Menu.cshtml** (the partial view):

```
@model IEnumerable<SportsStore.WebUI.Models.NavLink>

@foreach (var link in Model)
{
    @Html.RouteLink(link.Text, link.RouteValues);
}
```

**NavController.cs:**

```
namespace SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract;
    using SportsStore.WebUI.Models;


    public class NavController : Controller
    {
        private IProductsRepository productsRepository;


        public NavController(IProductsRepository productsRepository)
        {
            this.productsRepository = productsRepository;
        }


        public ViewResult Menu()
        {
            Func<string, NavLink> makeLink = categoryName => new NavLink
            {
                Text = categoryName ?? "Home",
                RouteValues = new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(
                    new
                    {
                        controller = "Products",
                        action = "List",
                        category = categoryName,
                        page = 1
                    })
            };

            List<NavLink> navLinks = new List<NavLink>
            {
                makeLink(null)
            };

            var categories = productsRepository.Products.Select(x => x.Category);

            foreach(var categoryName in categories.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x))
                navLinks.Add(makeLink(categoryName));

            return View(navLinks);
        }
    }
}
```

**NavLink.cs** (the View-Model class):

```
namespace SportsStore.WebUI.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Routing;


    public class NavLink
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public RouteValueDictionary RouteValues { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The following works fine when I use an ASCX Partial View, instead of a razor partial view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<SportsStore.WebUI.Models.NavLink>>" %>
<% foreach (var link in Model) { %>
    <%: Html.RouteLink(link.Text, link.RouteValues)%>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Did you ever actually get  this to work for Razor?

This is from the Apress Pro MVC 2 Framework book I'm guessing? I'm having the exact same problem trying to use Razor and no matter what I do (even Adam Tuliper's suggestions) I'm having no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use RenderAction and not RenderPartial as RenderPartial makes a copy of the current model used for whatever other view you are currently loading and sends it over to your view (and never executes your controller method). IE RenderPartial does not call your method .. only your view. RenderAction will call your controller method and then the partial view.

In your view use:

```
@Html.Action("Menu", "Nav")
```

Your route is simply (assuming a general nav bar and no parameters)

```
            routes.MapRoute(
    "NavMenu", // Route name
    "Nav/Menu", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Nav", action = "Menu"}
);
```

Comment: Thanks. If I update the above code to use RenderAction like: @Html.RenderAction("Menu"), I get the following error: "A public action method 'Menu' was not found on controller 'SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers.ProductsController'." Problem being of course, the Menu() function is in "NavController.cs" and not "ProductsController.cs"

Comment: You can specify RenderAction(action, controller) so @Html.RenderAction("Menu", "NavController") (make sure you have a route to get to this as well)

Comment: OK, that makes a lot of sense, so I've update it to @{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); }, but I'm struggling with the route. I have: routes.MapRoute(null, "???", new{ Controller = "Nav", action = "Menu" }); Obviously, I don't know what to put for the string/route

Comment: Ok, so I can't get this to work in razor, but it works fine with an ASPX partial view. Basically, the same exact code everywhere, but Menu.ascx (using webform syntax) works fine. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the Menu function in your controller to return PartialView

```
public PartialViewResult Menu()
{
    .
    .
    return PartialView(NavLinks)
}
```